# featured image not shown in create_posttype()

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a `create_posttype()` function as:

```
function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'movies',
        // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies'),
        )
    );
}
```

The function works but the featured image is not shown in the post. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try my source ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following this code to your functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

And set your `supports` with this code

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
```

You must register_post_type from beginning with another key.

And this is my full code worked.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Post Types 3', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Post Type 3', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types 3', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type 3', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image 3', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image 3', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image 3', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Post Type 3', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description 3', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

[image]

Comment: after adding    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );   to my function it works , thank u ,but when i replace my function with ur function , it not work, any way thank u so much

Comment: @AmelElreedy Okay bro. Maybe my function conflict with your exist function at some key value.... xD